# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'Trousers'

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm working on a marketplace where users will sell their products according to their categories. While making Update part of the CRUD on products, i had the following error:

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'Trousers' for column `jabea`.`products`.`category_id` at row 1 (SQL: update `products` set `category_id` = Trousers, `prod_name` = App, `products`.`updated_at` = 2023-08-03 02:18:28 where `id` = 6)

Here is my migration:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained('categories');
            $table->string('prod_name');
            $table->string('prod_image');
            $table->integer('prod_price');
            $table->integer('prod_qty');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Here is what i made

```
public function updateproduct(Request $request)
       {
        $request->validate
        ([
            "prod_name" => "required",
            "prod_price" => "required",
            "prod_qty" => "required",
            "category_id" => "required",
            "prod_image" => "image|nullable|max:1999"
        ]);

        $product = Product::find($request -> input('id'));
        $product->prod_name = $request->input(('prod_name'));
        $product->prod_price = $request->input(('prod_price'));
        $product->prod_qty = $request->input(('prod_qty'));
        $product->category_id = $request->input(('category_id'));

        if ($request->hasFile('prod_image')) {
            // *Get file name with extension
            $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('prod_image')->getClientOriginalName();
            // *Get only file name
            $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // *Get only extension
            $extension = $request->file('prod_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // *File name to store
            $fileNameToStore = $fileName . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            // *Upload
            $path = $request->file("prod_image")->storeAs('public/product_images', $fileNameToStore);

            if ($product->prod_image != "noimage.jpg") {
                Storage::delete('public/product_images/'.$product->prod_image);
            }

            $product->prod_image = $fileNameToStore;
        }

        $product->update();
        return redirect('/products')->with('status', 'Product successfully updated !!');
       }
```

Here is the updating form

```
{!! Form::open(['action'=>'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@updateproduct', 'method'=> 'POST']) !!}

                {{ csrf_field() }}

                @method('PUT')
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::hidden('id', $product->id, )}}
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product name</label>
                    <input  type="text" name="prod_name" value="{{$product->prod_name}}" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter product name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product Price (XAF)</label>
                    <input  type="number" name="prod_price" value="{{$product->prod_price}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter product price" min="1">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Qty</label>
                    <input  type="number" name="prod_qty" value="{{$product->prod_qty}}" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter the quantity" min="0">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Product category</label>
                    <select class="form-control select2" name="category_id" style="width: 100%;">
                      <option  selected="selected">{{$product->category->nom_categorie}}</option>
                        @foreach ($categories as $category)
                            <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->nom_categorie}}</option>

                        @endforeach
                    </select>

                  </div>
                  <label for="exampleInputFile">Product image</label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                      <input type="file" value="{{$product->prod_image}}" name="prod_image" class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile">
                      <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Update">
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I don't understant what the problem is and why i'm i getting this error.Need help please.

Thanks`

Comment: why request->input(('prod_name')) not request->input('prod_name')?

Comment: you should also validate "category_id" => "required,exists:categories,id",

Comment: Show the form that you're using to update the category_id

Comment: @UnderDog I just put the updating form

Comment: @OMR a mistake i did. Thanks i just corrected it in my code. But still the same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change your validation Rule for `category_id` to be

```
"category_id" => "required,exists:categories,id",
```

also, In your form, change the category section to be:

```
<select class="form-control select2" name="category_id" style="width: 100%;">
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{$category->id}}" {{$product->category_id == $category->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>
            {{$category->nom_categorie}}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: The provided answer solved the problem but the category_id rule you gave returned an error. So i put back the previous one and changed the form as adviced and it worked

Thanks